# Unknown keyboard language

Tags: keyboard, language-support, input-language

I'm a Linux newbie and I'm struggling with defining my keyboard setting. I googled and tried many solutions but didn't solve my problem. By system settings, I have Croatian keyboard but that isn't that keyboard, and I'm not sure is there any other way to find out what is the language my keyboard use for **real**?

I run Ubuntu on VMWare, maybe it's up to VMWare and not Ubuntu?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

`setxkbmap -print` is not helpful in this case. I found a [little tool](https://github.com/nonpop/xkblayout-state) ... very easy to compile

```
sudo apt-get install git
mkdir -p `~/src`
cd `~/src`
git clone https://github.com/nonpop/xkblayout-state.git 
cd xkblayout-state
make
```

Now you can execute the command `./xkblayout-state` to get the current layout, e.g.

```
./xkblayout-state print "%n"                          
German%
```

or list all layouts that are installed

```
./xkblayout-state print "%N"
German
English
English
```

<sup>In this case without a trailing `%`. I would have expected that, because I have not added a `\n`.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Go to system settings> text entry and add the desired keyboard layout

Comment: Unfortunately this is not helping, I've done this but everything stays the same. At the moment, there is Croatian keyboard on the list, but when I try to type - it's not Croatian keyboard definitely...

Comment: have you looked into the keyboard button on the same window as above and verify that it has the same keyboard layout

Comment: yes I looked, when I click on the keyboard button inside the window, picture of keyboard layout is opened and it shows correctly how the Croatian keyboard looks alike, but problem is that it is not producing when I try to type it on keyboard, I can't get desired letters or symbols like !"#$%&/()?*...when I tried with English keyboard, real situation on my keyboard is not corresponding to picture of English keyboard layout also. for example - shift+7 is '?' and should be '&' etc...